# Camel: route1 started and consuming from: Endpoint[...] but it is not consuming

Tags: web-services, rest, cxf, apache-camel, cxfrs

When I start camel in standalone mode I get a message that my routes are consuming from Endpoints that I have set up:

```
Route: route1 started and consuming from: Endpoint[http://localhost:9090/hrm/hrm_push?bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer]
```

Great!

But when I cut & past whats in between [] into my browser I'm getting a 404.
Surely if Camel says it is consuming at that address I should be able to use that address to contact my Rest web service.

Here is my appContext

```
<bean id="transformer" class="com.xxxx.portlistener.services.Transformer">
</bean> 

<cxf:rsServer id="pushServer" 
              address="http://localhost:9090/hrm/hrm_push?bindingStyle=SimpleConsumer" >
    <cxf:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="transformer" />
    </cxf:serviceBeans>
</cxf:rsServer>          

<cxf:rsServer id="pingServer" 
              address="http://localhost:9090/hrm/hrm_ping" >
    <cxf:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="transformer" />
    </cxf:serviceBeans>
</cxf:rsServer>

<!--  Camel Configuration -->
<camel:camelContext id="camel-1"  xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <package>com.xxxx.portlistener.services</package>
    <camel:route id="route1">
           <camel:from uri="cxfrs://bean://pushServer"/> 
           <camel:to uri="log:TEST?showAll=true" />
    </camel:route>   
    <camel:route id="route2">
           <camel:from uri="cxfrs://bean://pingServer"/> 
           <camel:to uri="log:TEST?showAll=true" />
    </camel:route>            
</camel:camelContext>
```

My Service Interface:

```
@Path("/hrm/")
public interface PushService
{
/**
 * trasform will change the given Object....
 */
@POST
@Produces("text/plain")
@Path("/hrm_push/")
public Response pusher(Object pushee);

@GET
@Produces("text/plain")
@Path("/hrm_ping/")
public Response ping();
}
```

The error from the console:

```
Jan 21, 2014 10:45:50 AM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSInInterceptor processRequest
WARNING: No root resource matching request path / has been found.
Jan 21, 2014 10:45:51 AM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.WebApplicationExceptionMapper toResponse
WARNING: WebApplicationException has been caught : no cause is available
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have duplicated path settings in the CXF RS bean and in the Java annotations. The two will be combined, therefore the final URL will be something like `http://localhost:9090/hrm/hrm_push` + `"/hrm/"` + `"/hrm_push/"` which is probably not what you wanted.

A recommendation would be to use the CXF RS bean to define the base URL only, then use the Java annotations for everything else.